# Processing is not communicating with Arduino Uno and the console is spouting garbage

Tags: process, arduino, console, processing, arduino-uno

I'm working on making a small [G4P](https://sourceforge.net/projects/g4p/) GUI as test for Arduino communication.

[Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUWoW.png)

So it’s just basic: when X button is pressed, send Y to the console, and the Arduino does whatever with Y, but the [Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) console is just full of garbage.

[The trash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZMWA.png)

[Arduino wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn1LF.png)

Here is the code for the Arduino:

```cpp
int rLED = 7;
int gLED = 8;
int R = 11;
int G = 12;
int B = 13;

void setup() {
  pinMode(rLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gLED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char state = Serial.read();
    if(state == '1')
    {
      digitalWrite (rLED, HIGH);
    }
    if(state == '2')
    {
      digitalWrite (rLED, LOW);
    }
    if(state == '3')
    {
      digitalWrite (gLED, HIGH);
    }
    if(state == '4')
    {
      digitalWrite (gLED, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code for Processing:

```java
import processing.serial.*;

// Need G4P library
import g4p_controls.*;

Serial myPort;

public void setup() {
  size(480, 320, JAVA2D);
  createGUI();
  customGUI();
  // Place your setup code here
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 9600);
}

public void draw() {
  background(230);
}

public void handleButtonEvents(GButton button, GEvent event) {
  if (button == rLED && event == GEvent.CLICKED) {
    myPort.write('1');
    delay(100);
    myPort.write('2');
  }
  if (button == button1 && event == GEvent.CLICKED) {
    myPort.write('3');
    delay(100);
    myPort.write('4');
  }
}

// Use this method to add additional statements
// to customise the GUI controls
public void customGUI() {

}
```

Here is the code for the GUI (Processing):

```processing
public void Red_Blink(GButton source, GEvent event) { // _CODE_:rLED:951221:
  println("rLED - GButton >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
} // _CODE_:rLED:951221:

public void Green_Blink(GButton source, GEvent event) { // _CODE_:button1:443069:
  println("button1 - GButton >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
} // _CODE_:button1:443069:

public void Red_int(GCustomSlider source, GEvent event) { // _CODE_:Red:702179:
  println("custom_slider1 - GCustomSlider >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
} // _CODE_:Red:702179:

public void Green_int(GCustomSlider source, GEvent event) { // _CODE_:Green:645891:
  println("custom_slider2 - GCustomSlider >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
} // _CODE_:Green:645891:

public void Blue_int(GCustomSlider source, GEvent event) { // _CODE_:Blue:372420:
  println("Blue - GCustomSlider >> GEvent." + event + " @ " + millis());
} // _CODE_:Blue:372420:


// Create all the GUI controls.
// autogenerated do not edit
public void createGUI() {
  G4P.messagesEnabled(false);
  G4P.setGlobalColorScheme(GCScheme.GOLD_SCHEME);
  G4P.setCursor(ARROW);
  surface.setTitle("Controll panel ");
  tittle = new GLabel(this, 180, 10, 150, 30);
  tittle.setTextAlign(GAlign.CENTER, GAlign.MIDDLE);
  tittle.setText("Controll arduino");
  tittle.setTextBold();
  tittle.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
  tittle.setOpaque(false);
  rLED = new GButton(this, 60, 80, 80, 30);
  rLED.setText("blink red LED");
  rLED.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.RED_SCHEME);
  rLED.addEventHandler(this, "Red_Blink");
  button1 = new GButton(this, 150, 80, 80, 30);
  button1.setText("blink greed LED");
  button1.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.GREEN_SCHEME);
  button1.addEventHandler(this, "Green_Blink");
  Red = new GCustomSlider(this, 20, 140, 440, 40, "grey_blue");
  Red.setShowValue(true);
  Red.setLimits(150, 0, 255);
  Red.setNumberFormat(G4P.INTEGER, 0);
  Red.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.RED_SCHEME);
  Red.setOpaque(false);
  Red.addEventHandler(this, "Red_int");
  Green = new GCustomSlider(this, 18, 200, 440, 40, "grey_blue");
  Green.setShowValue(true);
  Green.setLimits(50, 0, 255);
  Green.setNumberFormat(G4P.INTEGER, 0);
  Green.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.GREEN_SCHEME);
  Green.setOpaque(false);
  Green.addEventHandler(this, "Green_int");
  label1 = new GLabel(this, 200, 130, 80, 20);
  label1.setTextAlign(GAlign.CENTER, GAlign.MIDDLE);
  label1.setText("Red");
  label1.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
  label1.setOpaque(false);
  label2 = new GLabel(this, 200, 190, 80, 20);
  label2.setTextAlign(GAlign.CENTER, GAlign.MIDDLE);
  label2.setText("Green");
  label2.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
  label2.setOpaque(false);
  Blue = new GCustomSlider(this, 20, 260, 440, 40, "grey_blue");
  Blue.setShowValue(true);
  Blue.setLimits(150, 0, 255);
  Blue.setNumberFormat(G4P.INTEGER, 0);
  Blue.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
  Blue.setOpaque(false);
  Blue.addEventHandler(this, "Blue_int");
  label3 = new GLabel(this, 200, 250, 80, 20);
  label3.setTextAlign(GAlign.CENTER, GAlign.MIDDLE);
  label3.setText("Blue");
  label3.setLocalColorScheme(GCScheme.BLUE_SCHEME);
  label3.setOpaque(false);
}

// Variable declarations
// autogenerated do not edit
GLabel tittle;
GButton rLED;
GButton button1;
GCustomSlider Red;
GCustomSlider Green;
GLabel label1;
GLabel label2;
GCustomSlider Blue;
GLabel label3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the Processing code in the setup() function.

Try this:

```cpp
String portName = Serial.list()[0];
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
```